# ReactJS | How to set my sidebar to be always in front'

Tags: html, css

I'm currently doing a personal project to improve my skills in React JS. I've placed a sidebar that routes between tabs and so far it is okay but as soon as I scroll down to my charts, the charts is showed in front and does not get covered by the sidebar unlike my other div with the user profile.
[[image: Home page1]

This happens when I open my sidebar which is okay
[image: The sidebar is shown as expected]

As soon as I scrolled down to my Recharts, it starts to get weird. The charts is like in a front layer and cover up my sidebar.

[image]

Comment: What if you use `z-index` in CSS ?

Comment: Check your z-index

Comment: I cant seem to find the problem, another note is that the userprofile and the map is on the same div, the charts are separate divs. Thanks

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, though it did not worked on the charts, it definitely worked on my map since it has the same problem. I believe that the problem is in the charts not the div because I tried placing it in my userprofile, it did cover up the image and the names but not the charts. I hope I explained it well.

https://imgur.com/a/LkULuMU

Comment: when you open your side bar add margin-left on content that will solve your problem

Comment: Hi, problem solved. Turns out it there was another div that has lower z-index than the charts (not exactly the sidebar, but the div that the sidebar resides in). Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set zIndex of sidebar higher than charts zIndex. Im not sure if it's correct solution, but it should work.

Comment: Hi, it worked for me on my maps because it has similar issues but not for the charts, I tried placing my chart in my userprofile and it cover up everything inside it except the chart :(

https://imgur.com/a/LkULuMU

Comment: So try to find zIndex of charts, and make sure that sidebar has higher zIndex

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with z-index. However you need to make sure the position is something other than `position: static;` which is the default.

So try this.

```
z-index: 999;
position: relative;
```